Select from all table in grafana
this query works well but tables will be added every month so I would like it to give me the distinct results of the name column for all the tables in the database, without having to mark the names of the tables, like using the result of the output show tables but I didn't succeed.
    SELECT `Name (Configuration Item)` FROM 2023_05_23
    UNION
    SELECT `Name (Configuration Item)` FROM 2024_11_22
    UNION
    SELECT `Name (Configuration Item)` FROM 2023_01_22
    UNION
    SELECT `Name (Configuration Item)` FROM 2024_05_12
) AS CombinedResults

I do this query with grafana. I tried to do my query with set, prapare, execute but it seems that this kind of manipulation not works in this environment. And so this didn't work either :
$tables = mysql_query("show tables");
$string = '';
while ($table_data = mysql_fetch_row($tables)){
    $string.=$table_data[0].',';
}   
$ALL_TABLES = substr($string,0,strlen($string)-1);
$sql="SELECT `Name (Configuration Item)` FROM $ALL_TABLES ";

So is there a way to obtain the desired result in a single query and without putting tables of the same structure in the same table (even if it's not great)?

Is this part of a larger query or are you just trying to select the values from this one column across multiple tables? You could use a stored procedure to dynamically build up the SQL (if the table names can be identified programmatically) but some comments suggest this can only be done for time series data in Grafana.
